# sql - multiple FK columns from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables, one for teams and other for their schedules.

```
table teams
int teamId
varchar teamName

table sched
int schedId
date startDate
time startTime
int awayTeam
int homeTeam
```

How do I write the query that get the names for both teams?

This one doesn't quite do the trick -

```
select s.schedId,s.awayTeam,t.teamName,s.homeTeam,t.teamName
from sched s, teams t
where s.schedId=1
and t.teamId=s.homeTeam and t.teamId=s.awayTeam
```

I know my and clause is incorrect, but what should it really be?

Thanks
RD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
SELECT sched.*, at.teamName AS awayteam, ht.teamName AS hometeam FROM sched 
    JOIN teams AS at ON sched.awayteam = at.teamId
    JOIN teams AS ht ON sched.hometeam = ht.teamId;
```

You can join one table several times - but you will need to use aliases for them, to form correct where-clauses.

Notice, that this: `FROM a JOIN b ON a.fk = b.id` has the same effect as this: `FROM a,b WHERE a.fk = b.id`